# Log User Out Only on browser or tab close

Tags: javascript, browser, navigation, logout

Hi There im looking for a way to log a user out of my site **ONLY** if they close the tab or browser.

At the moment im just trying to alert a message on tab close or browser close but cant find a solution anywhere.

I've done research and come across onbeforeunload, however it alerts every time you try to navigate to a different page in the site.

i need to be able to navigate through the site and perform functions and only perform an action on close.

Current code (alerts message every time you navigate)

```
<script>
  function closeIt()
  {
      if (window.closed) {
          return "Any string value here forces a dialog box to \n" +
               "appear before closing the window.";
      }
  }
  window.onbeforeclose = closeIt;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First detect browser tab close:

```
   $(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
        return confirm("Do you really want to close? This will log you out of your profile."); 
    });
});
```

Than change your login preference based on return value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload